# Resetting a jQuery input field character countdown after the form has been submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I aim to limit a form input to 220 characters. I can do this with some server side PHP and the `maxlength` attribute.

My problem relates to a character countdown I am displaying on the page which shows the user how many characters they have left before they've reached the maximum they can type in the input field.

I've got as far as the demo below.

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/GPmq8/

You will see that the counter decreases as the user types into the input field. This bit is working.

After the user has submitted the form, I'd like the counter to return to 220 (i.e. reset itself). How can I modify my script to do that? **Note**, my form is submitted via AJAX so there is no page reload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any form tag in your example, but you can try when someone click submit restore the values of the `input`

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Type something..." class="form-entry" name="form-entry" rows="1" maxlength="220" value="" />
<div><button name='Mybutton' id='MyButton'>Submit</button></div>
<hr />
<span class="countdown"></span>

function updateCountdown() {
    // 220 is the max message length
    var remaining = 220 - jQuery('.form-entry').val().length;
    jQuery('.countdown').text(remaining + '');
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    updateCountdown();
    $('.form-entry').change(updateCountdown);
    $('.form-entry').keyup(updateCountdown);

    $('#MyButton').click(function(){
        jQuery('.countdown').text('220');
        jQuery('.form-entry').val('');

    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GPmq8/

Comment: Sorry, I omitted the form tag to keep it brief. The problem with this approach is when someone clicks submit - the counter resets but the form no longer submits.

Comment: it's the concept, if you paste the full code we can give you the full solution, please remember to make validations in the server side too, NEVER trust in the users

Comment: jQuery('.countdown').text('220'); certainly does answer my question - it resets the countdown after submission. I'm sure i'll be able to get the form submitting somehow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just reset the input field to an empty string after submitting it. Your counter will be reset by your present code.
You can do this by adding the following line to your script where your ajax returns (eg. `success`).

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: '/YOUR.php',
     data: formData,
     success: function (data) {
          $('.form-entry').val(''); 
     }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The script I am using can be found here: https://github.com/Automattic/liveblog/blob/master/js/liveblog.js - I'm not entirely sure how to incorporate $('.form-entry').val(''); into it?

Comment: Hi, i had a quick read over the code. Somewhere I found `success: success_callback` inside `liveblog.ajax_request`. So in your page with your input field there should be some kind of calling `liveblog.ajax_request` with its parameters (which is used to send the content of the input field to the php script). There you have to insert `function() { $('.form-entry').val(''); };` as third parameter.

Comment: Thanks for investigating. I've opted to avoid modifying the plugin in case I need to update at a future date. jcho360's jQuery('.countdown').text('220'); seemed to do the trick. +1'd your answer as I can see how it could be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

On the success event of the ajax call, reset your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
function resetCountdown(){
 $('.countdown').text('220');
 $('.form-entry').val('');  
}

$.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    resetCountdown();
});
```